# Dragging an object in one line

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, 2d, drag

I am trying to make a dragging effect. I have a project where u are supposed to pull a bone out of meat. The dragging is working, but when i grab the bone i can move it in all directions. What i would like to achieve is that i can only drag it in one direction. On the images below i mean the red line. I tried many things but nothing worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

I used these functions for the dragging.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    offset = this.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
    transform.position = curPosition;
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this is supposed to only move in the direction of the red arrow? if so, do you know the degrees that the red arrow is in relation to the object? Does the red arrow ever change angles? If not, can we assume it's always at a 45 degree angle?

Comment: Yes, only in the direction of the red arrow. Well each of the objects has different rotation so its not always 45.

Comment: Ahh, arrows that can change angles makes this a little more complicated. Now we're getting into the y=mx+b equation to determine how many X and Y units each mousedrag needs to move the units. I would start in getting the image to move at the 45 degree angles first, and then build on top of that to allow for different angles.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the right thing to do. Can i just ask where should i put the Y + offset and X + offset in the code? I

Comment: Yes, it would be: `Vector3 newPostion= new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x + offset, Input.mousePosition.y + offset);` And then set the position of the bone to that `newPosition`. I.E - `transform.position = newPosition`

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `x` component of your mouse and use `localPosition`:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    offset = this.transform.localPosition - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(transform.localPosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector2(transform.localPosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint);
    Vector3 curPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x, 0f, 0f) + offset;
    transform.localPosition = curPosition;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt let me multiply by a Vector3,  it says that  Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type Vector3

Comment: @Richarrd82 Didn't see that offset was a Vector3 too :) i edited my answer

Comment: I messed up and i left something in the code. Instead of the transform.position.x there is supposed to be Input.mousePosition.x

Comment: Shouldn't `curScreenPoint = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y)` ? Also, if you're moving the Yellow Arrow, the offset needs to move the transform  `Y + offset` and `X - offset`. If you're moving the red arrow, it needs to be `Y + offset` and `X + offset` to make sure it's moving in the 45 degree directions.